# How can I set a required attribute of my base class using Class::Std?

Tags: perl, oop

I am working with multiple different versions of Perl (all 5.8+) across different operating systems.  I am unable to manage modules on various machines which has led me to use a combination of Class::Std and the base pragma to facilitate OO Perl and inheritance.

I want to set a required attribute of my base class when constructing the subclass object.  Additionally, I want to do so without explicitly specifying the value within the arguments sent to my subclass since it will be the same for all objects of the given subclass.

The following code (followed by a question) illustrates this scenario:

My base class:

```
package Person;

use Class::Std;

# class data
my %person_title                :ATTR( name => "title"      );
my %person_name                 :ATTR( name => "name"       );
1;
```

My subclass:

```
package Doctor;

use Class::Std;

# set inheritance
use base 'Person';

# class data
my %doctor_specialty            :ATTR( name => "specialty"      );
1;
```

My script (this currently fails with "Missing initializer label for Person: 'title'"):

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Doctor;

my %args = (
    "name"      => "John Smith",
    "specialty" => "Dentist",
);

Doctor->new(\%args);
```

When I create a Doctor object, I always want the 'title' to be 'Dr.'.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: My attempts to explicitly specify a value for 'title' within Doctor's BUILD() and START() methods was not successful.  I'm unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: Class::Std is not recommended, is there a particular reason you're using it?

Comment: If you do not already have substantial investment in `Class::Std`, leave it behind. Damian has a lot of good ideas, but this one was a dud.

Comment: If you're really stuck with Class::Std, you can do this by overriding `new` in the subclass as described in [Overriding arguments in Class::Std superclass constructors](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=566829) on PerlMonks.

Comment: Moose is not available across all machines, neither is 'parent'.